# Transit time at Schiphol

Tags: transit, amsterdam, ams

I am coming in from Detroit by flight DL 138 at 11:15 and taking 
flight DL 9574 at 12:55 to Delhi on a single ticket. Do I have enough time to connect?

Comment: Similar to http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/22092/4584